# Updating a field in a table based on the sum of all previous dates in another table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, database-design

Here is a simplified version of two tables that I have set up like this:

```
Users (Name(varchar), DateAdded(date))
Costs (Month(date), TotalUsers(int))
```

Now whenever I insert, update, or delete the DateAdded in the Users table, I want to update the appropriate rows in the Costs table.  So if I delete a row in the users table from January 2011, all rows in the Costs table that have a Date value later than January 2011 in the Month cloumn need to have their TotalUsers field decremented.  For example in this case rows with Febuary 2011 and March 2011 would need to decrement their TotalUsers but a row with Dec 2010 would not.

Basically whenever I change a row in Users, I want to change each row in costs so that its TotalUsers field represents the sum of all dates in the Users table before its own.  I'm currently using a trigger set up on insert delete but I'm not sure the best way to update the costs table without using a cursor.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?7

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you create a view on Users instead that will produce the right months and counts each time

```
Create View dbo.VCosts
with schemabinding
AS
SELECT MONTH(DateAdded) Month, COUNT_BIG(*) TotalUsers
From dbo.Users
Group by MONTH(DateAdded)
```

If you need the data to be persisted (stored) for [performance reasons](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx), you can create an [INDEXED VIEW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) to materialize the view.  It is automatically maintained so you don't have to fiddle around with triggers.

```
create unique clustered index cix_VCosts on VCosts(Month)
```

If you had other columns in your Costs table, then keep these two columns out and join to this view by Month to get the data.